# Rails 4 not able to get the actual website url stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a string field in my User table where I store the user's github website url. Now, I am trying to show the link on the user's profile page.
Instead of getting 'https://www.github.com'(example link)...I am getting "localhost/users/www.github.com".
I tried it the following way :-

```
<% if @user.github? %>
    <a href="<%= "#{@user.github}" %>"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i></a>
<% end %>
```

On clicking the link, I get localhost/users/www.github.com instead of just www.github.com. How can this be done correctly ?

Comment: URLs need to be prefixed with a 'http://' if they're to be absolute URLs.

Comment: Thank you @sevenseacat, that worked !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url is without the "https://". you can try following or save it all urs with "https://","http://"

```
<% if @user.github? %>
  <a href="<%= "https://#{@user.github}" %>"><i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i></a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you @Shani, the link is now properly showing !